# SQL IF else in where statement

Tags: sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CourseEvalRpt_2]
    @coursetitle varchar(100) = null,
    @datestart varchar(8),
    @dateend varchar(8)
AS
    select distinct 
        t_empname, t_leader, T_Dept, t_submit 
    from 
        tbltrain
    where 
        t_category like 'course%' 
        and 
           if (@coursetitle <> '') t_course = @coursetitle end
```

How can I eliminate the SQL where criteria when parameter name `@coursetitle` is empty? I don't want to add the `t_course` condition when @coursetitle is empty, so system will display all data rather than set the t_course=''.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Side note (if using **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sql to this:

```
select distinct t_empname,
       t_leader,
       T_Dept,
       t_submit 
  from tbltrain
 where t_category like 'course%' 
   and ( (@coursetitle<>''and t_course=@coursetitle) 
         or @coursetitle='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `where` clause to:

```
where t_category like 'course%' and
      (@coursetitle = '' or t_course = @coursetitle)
```

If you used `NULL` instead of an empty string for `@coursetitle`, you could phrase it as:

```
where t_category like 'course%' and
      t_course = coalesce(@coursetitle, t_course)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using dynamic SQL ? so that you can perform a clear `IF ELSE` condition.

Just add `SQLQuery` variable for the SQL query and use dynamic SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CourseEvalRpt_2]

@coursetitle varchar(100)=null,
@datestart varchar(8),
@dateend varchar(8),
@SQLQuery varchar(max) -->> Additional variable for dynamic SQL
AS

SET @SQLQuery = 'select distinct t_empname,t_leader,T_Dept,t_submit 
                 from tbltrain where t_category like course%'

IF ISNULL(@coursetitle,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
       SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'AND t_course = ' + @coursetitle 
    END

EXEC (@SQLQuery)
```